# Should data classes be reused across layers and applications or mapped into layer specific classes?

Tags: c#, architecture, dependency-injection, decoupling

I am creating a WPF application that uses a WCF service to interact with the data source. I use DI for both the client and the WCF server to ensure decoupled code, but I am unsure how to handle the data transfer from backend to user interface.

To keep the layers separate data is currently transferred from the database to the UI through several mapping steps. On the server side data entities are mapped to domain objects which again are mapped to service data contracts. On the client side WCF proxy classes are mapped to viewmodels.

Some developers at work claim that this "copying" of data between seemingly identical classes creates a maintenance problem because so many classes must be updated when a change is introduced. Instead they say you should use shared classes across the layers since we control both the client application and the WCF service. I too worry about the amount of work involved and see a potential performance penalty, but on the other hand using a shared class across the layers/abstractions might create tight coupling the way I see it. What is the best approach?

Comment: Sharing WCF data classes may not be feasible in all scenarios. For example, if you use WCF attributes to change the names of properties and types returned by services the generated classes are going to be defined in the WCF service assembly. This makes all clients depend on the WCF service to enable sharing. Just to say this can put real-life constraints on the amout of sharing that's actually accomplished.

Answer (score 9):

Using DTOs as business objects is not the best decision you can make.
From my experience I can say that usually when your objects are identical for all the layers then there is probably a problem with the architecture somewhere.

In a real business scenario it is quite unlikely that a business logic on a server and a business logic on a client have the same context and operate with the same objects. And if they have exactly the same structure with the database... hmmm... sounds like a data-driven application.

But if it **is** a data-driven application when clients access some data, modify it and save it back, then probably you don't really need this complicated layering? It sounds simple so let's keep it simple. If it **is** a data-driven application, why not just create a [WCF DataServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) context on top of your database and let it do all the dirty work for you when you just access your data over WCF without even thinking about DTOs, mappings, etc.

If it is **not** a data-driven application, then you probably have some complicated business logic on your server side, and this business logic usually operates with objects that make sense only its context. It just doesn't make sense to push these object all the way through to the UI.

Instead, the UI will probably send *commands* to the server in order to ask the system *to do something*. For example, it will send a "DisableAccount(id=123)" command instead of loading AccountDTO, changing its IsEnabled flag to false and pushing it back.
If there **is** a business logic, then it probably will be triggered by such *command* from the client who does not need to know *how to* disable accounts or how to do other things. It just knows and can *command* the system *to do* something.

So in this scenario client (the UI) just does not need the same object that server has. It may need some data to display to user, but it definitely will be in a format that make sense for the client's view, not for the business logic. It will probably contain some denormalized data, combined somehow.

Say, User for UI is not a DTO mapped to the Users table. It is another DTO, containing users data and statistics from different tables, processed somehow. Client does not need to know the internal structure of server's data storage so there is no need to expose it. Get the relevant data and send the appropriate commands, that's it.

Saying all this I should underline that it is NOT a binary choice you make. For simple features you may use a simple approach, for the features where having business logic make sense you may do the other things.

You do not have to choose one for everything. So you do not have to *always* create 3 similar objects just because it is "The Way" or *always* pass entities all the way through to the UI.
But what you *will* have to do is to clearly separate contexts and to define where which approach is going to be used.

In 80% you will probably end up with something simple (like WCF DataServices), and you don't need to do anything, and it is fine as in a lot of operations you just want to change the data.

But in other 20% (which is the "core" of your application) where the real business logic lives - here you may want this kind of separation not only for objects, but also for responsibilities between your layers.

Answer (score 7):

All that mapping indeed creates a maintenance burden. Whether or not it's warranted depends on what you are building, and how complex the business logic is.

However, it's very important to realize that [once you start sharing data structures across layers and tiers, the architecture is no longer decoupled](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorthTheMapping.aspx). If you do that, **you'd essentially be building a monolithic application**. Don't get me wrong: there's nothing wrong with building a monolithic application if all you're doing is a glorified CRUD application, but it's essential to make that decision explicitly.

There's at least these alternatives:

- Maintain strict layering. The mapping cost remains, but the code is decoupled.
- Build a monolithic application. Collapse everything you can collapse. Keep it as simple as possible. It's going to be tightly coupled, but it just may become so simple that it doesn't matter.
- Do something radically different, like building a [CQRS](http://abdullin.com/cqrs) application or a SOA mashup.

Personally, I prefer the third option these days.

Comment: What about Value Objects (like `Distance`, `Point`, `Triangle`, `Money`, `MailAddress`) that come from Domain Layer. Should their classes be also duplicated in Service Layer in order to maintain strict layering?

Comment: @Lightman I find that I often need to do this when I create a layered architecture, because Value Objects should be immutable, which tends to fit poorly with boundary concerns like event-based GUIs or (de)serialization of values across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing sacred about layers.  Having layer-specific versions of each and every entity in the model would increase the number of classes a great deal.  It's unnecessary, in my view.  It violates the DRY principle: why keep repeating yourself?

What does layer purity buy you?

So I'd say the best approach is to pass those model entities around without fear.